# Solution to a second order difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, finite-differences

Suppose we have two sequences $\{a_k\}, \{b_k\}$ satisfying following difference equation
\begin{align*}
a_{k+1} = \alpha_1 a_k + \alpha_2 a_{k-1} + b_k + \frac 1 k,
\end{align*}
where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 > 0$ are fixed constants.

What is a good way to write down the solution explicitly in terms of $a_1, a_0$ and $\{b_k\}$? I tried to expand $a_k, a_{k-1}$ but lost track half way. It seems this method is too cumbersome.

---

UPDATE: I realize we can define $c_{k+1} = (a_{k+1}, a_k)^T$ and $d_k = ( b_k + \frac 1 k, b_{k-1} + \frac 1 {k-1})^T$, $ B =\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. The difference equation is equivalent to
$$ c_{k+1} = B c_k + d_k.$$ Then we have $c_{k+1} = B^k c_1 + d_k + B d_{k-1} + \dots + B^{k} d_1$. But still I could not see some explicit pattern to write down the solution to $a_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variation of parameters would be the way to attack an equivalent linear differential equation and it seems to work OK for this difference equation as well. For simplicity I am going to recast your difference equation as
$$a_{k+2}-(r_1+r_2)a_{k+1}+r_1r_2a_k=b_k$$
That amounts to ny $b_k$ being identified with your $b_{k+1}+\frac1{k+1}$ and $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of $r^2-\alpha_1r-\alpha_2=0$. We assume $r_1r_2\ne0$ because then it would be a first order difference equation and also $r_1\ne r_2$; that's a separate case to be worked out if necessary. Then the general solution to the homogeneous difference equation
$$a_{h,k+2}-(r_1+r_2)a_{h,k+1}+r_1r_2a_{h,k}=0$$
Is
$$a_{h,k}=xr_1^k+yr_2^k$$
We hope to solve the inhomogeneous difference equation with a solution of the form
$$a_k=x_kr_1^k+y_kr_2^k$$
On taking differences,
$$a_{k+1}=x_{k+1}r_1^{k+1}+y_{k+1}r_2^{k+1}$$
We would like
$$a_{k+1}=x_{k}r_1^{k+1}+y_{k}r_2^{k+1}$$
And this will be so provided
$$(x_{k+1}-x_k)r_1^{k+1}+(y_{k+1}-y_k)r_2^{k+1}=0$$
On the second difference,
$$\begin{align}a_{k+2}&=x_{k+2}r_1^{k+2}+y_{k+2}r_2^{k+2}\\
&=(x_{k+2}-x_{k+1})r_1^{k+2}+(y_{k+2}-y_{k+1})r_2^{k+2}+x_{k+1}r_1^{k+2}+y_{k+1}r_2^{k+2}\\
&=x_{k+1}r_1^{k+2}+y_{k+1}r_2^{k+2}\\
&=(r_1+r_2)\left(x_{k+1}r_1^{k+1}+y_{k+1}r_2^{k+1}\right)-r_1r_2\left(x_kr_1^k+y_kr_2^k\right)+b_k\\
&=x_{k+1}r_1^{k+2}+y_{k+1}r_2^{k+2}+x_{k+1}r_1^{k+1}r_2+y_{k+1}r_1r_2^{k+1}-r_1r_2\left(x_kr_1^k+y_kr_2^k\right)+b_k\end{align}$$
So
$$\begin{align}0&=r_1r_2\left(x_{k+1}-x_k\right)r_1^k+r_1r_2\left(y_{k+1}-y_k\right)r_2^k+b_k\\
&=r_1r_2\left(x_{k+1}-x_k\right)r_1^k-r_1r_2\left(x_{k+1}-x_k\right)\frac{r_1^{k+1}}{r_2}+b_k\\
&=r_1^{k+1}\left(r_2-r_1\right)\left(x_{k+1}-x_k\right)+b_k\end{align}$$
This is a telescoping series for $x_k$ so we find that
$$x_k=x_0+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{b_j}{(r_1-r_2)r_1^{j+1}}$$
Similarly,
$$y_k=y_0+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{b_j}{(r_2-r_1)r_2^{j+1}}$$
We have the initial conditions
$$\begin{align}a_0&=x_0+y_0\\
a_1&=r_1x_1+r_2y_1=r_1x_0+r_2y_0\end{align}$$
With solutions
$$\begin{align}x_0&=\frac{a_1-r_2a_0}{r_1-r_2}\\
y_0&=\frac{a_1-r_1a_0}{r_2-r_1}\end{align}$$
So now we have
$$\begin{align}a_k&=x_kr_1^k+y_kr_2^k\\
&=\frac{a_1-r_2a_0}{r_1-r_2}r_1^k+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{b_jr_1^{k-j-1}}{r_1-r_2}+\frac{a_1-r_1a_0}{r_2-r_1}r_2^k+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{b_jr_2^{k-j-1}}{r_2-r_1}\end{align}$$
Substituting the above solution into the original difference equation shows that it is valid.

Comment: In the solution, should $b_k$ be $b_j$ instead?

Comment: @jing007 Thanks, I had just made a pass through my post to clean up typos, but I guess this shows once again that $\infty-\infty\ne0$.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer.

Comment: I forgot why I was convinced. But now I am confused by the line " We would like $a_{k+1} = x_k r_1^{k+1} + y_k r_2^{k+1}$." How do we get to this?

Comment: We are trying to replace a difficult second-order difference equation with $2$ easier first-order ones. With $2$ variable sequences we can choose one of the equations they must satisfy at our discretion, and the one you quoted above is our choice. The second equation follows from our choice and the actual difference equation. The choice is made by analogy with the [variation of parameters](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx) method for solving differential equations.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing out.